# How to override page.tpl.php for given content type?

Tags: 7, theming

Please suggest that naming convention for content type

content type machine name : test_content

I need to define separate page.tpl for this content type.

I tried page--test_content.tpl.php and cleared cache. But that template is not activared.
Any issue in naming convention.